# How I can get rid of error while decoding strings or how to properly decode such strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to decode file I found, it has hexadecimal numbers, some ASCII encoded characters and some untouched characters. I wrote a program but I get an error "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int". Perhaps you can suggest another solution.

This is the code I'm using:

```
def decode_code(code):
    decoded_code = ""

    i = 0
    while i < len(code):
        c = code[i]

        if c.isdigit() or c.isalpha():
            end = i + 1
            while end < len(code) and (code[end].isdigit() or code[end].isalpha()):
                end += 1

            if c == "_" and i == 0:
                i = end
                continue

            try:
                decoded = int(code[i:end], 16)
                decoded_code += chr(decoded)
            except ValueError:
                pass

            i = end

        else:
            decoded_code += c
            i += 1

    return decoded_code

code = "Here is text that im trying to decode"

decoded_code = decode_code(code)
print(decoded_code)
```

And here is some of code that I'm trying to decode:

```
"function initNLRM(){const _0x2ee85c={'NXahI':function(_0x183c20,_0x21ef18){return _0x183c20(_0x21ef18);},'BjPoh':'0|1|3|4|2','cgEBA':function(_0x4cd723,_0x5c383c){return _0x4cd723==_0x5c383c;},'DaXUt':function(_0x3d8f2f,_0x4a5ba8){return _0x3d8f2f&&_0x4a5ba8;}"
```

I only know how to use Python, so I don't know what language it is and if I'm doing the right thing. How can I get rid of the error, or how can I otherwise decode the string?

Comment: What do you mean by "decoding" this string? It's already decoded and it's apparently some JavaScript code if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What do you think you're going to get out of that?  This is Javascript that has been intentionally shrouded, like malware.  ALL of the hex numbers in that are randomly generated variable names.  They aren't integers, and you aren't going to learn anything from their values.

Comment: When I run your code I do not get any error but I get many spaces in the output. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Caridorc im using 3.10 python

Comment: @TimRoberts Not necessarily malware, many legit sites use obfuscation just to protect their IP.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry, I just don't really understand how it works.

Comment: How WHAT works?  This is just a snippet of some larger code.  It's setting up a "library" if functions.  The `NXahI` function is an indirect function call.  If you call that function with `f(a,b)`, it uses `a` as the function and `b` as the parameter, so it returns `a(b)`.  The `cgEBA` function returns true if the two parameters are equal.  The `DaXut` function is a logical "and"; returns true if both parameters are true.  There's nothing interesting to learn here.

Comment: As others have said, there is nothing to "decode" here.  It is just Javascript code that uses weird names for its variables.